# Window borders disappear

Tags: window-manager

I have a new install of Ubuntu 11.04 and sometimes the window borders will disappear. How do I prevent this or at least get them back without logging out and logging back in (which means close all my programs)?

I have installed WINE but it is not running, but seems to make it happen more often I think when it is running, probably just cause of the exe I am running.

I probably have an out of date Ubuntu because I have no internet and I think Ubuntu comes out of date when you get the ISO, but if there was a patch I needed, I can install it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a command line, run :

```
compiz-decorator --replace
```

Answer (score 4):

I had something similar where compiz and metacity where not working well together.

try `compiz --replace &`

I had to stop doing it after updating though.

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu 11.04 used new kernel and has some bugs. Border problem is one of them. If your computer is old one or low graphics configure then i prefer to use 10.04. 10.04 is the most stable version of ubuntu i ever see. 
To get back border follow amosrivera's suggestion.

Comment: I wish somebody told me that before I installed/configured/personalized 11.04 :(